# R color the y axis values in a base graphics plot each with a different colour

Tags: r

I am trying to  color the y axis values in a base graphics plot each with a different colour but I cannot work out how to do it.
Something like:

```
 plot(1:5,col.ylabels= c("red","orange","yellow","green","blue"))
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to suppress the initial axis values and replace with custom `text`.

```
plot(1:5, col = c("red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue"), yaxt = 'n')
lablist <- as.vector(c(1:5))
text(par("usr")[1] - 0.4, 1:5 + 0.25,
     labels = lablist, pos = 1, xpd = TRUE, 
     col = c("red","orange","yellow","green","blue"))
```

I added color to the example at https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/faq/how-can-i-change-the-angle-of-the-value-labels-on-my-axes/ by referencing the documentation at `?text`.

[image]